# Getting attributes set of a view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I am using a custom inflater to inflate a layout. I have the rootView of the layout. Now I want to check for all the child views that have **text attr** set in it.

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/hello_world"
```

The child view could be anything (TextView, Labelm EditText, etc.). How can I get the attributes defined for a view. I tried the following code but couldn't get the string (returns null)

```
int[] textSizeAttr = new int[] { android.R.attr.text };
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue(); 
TypedArray a= childView.getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, textSizeAttr);
```

How do I get the attributes of a view? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Guru_VL I am not using any custom view. I just want the attributes of the view defined in any given layout xml file. I am using a custom inflater hoping to get those details. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I am creating a library that will change the text being displayed on any application. I want to know how can I get all the view and their text value?

Comment: Do you have any updates?